Issues Connecting to Infor Data Lake Using Spark JDBC in Azure Synapse Spark Notebook
I'm encountering difficulties while attempting to connect to Infor Data Lake using Spark JDBC within Azure Synapse. Despite configuring the necessary JDBC driver and ionapi file path, I consistently encounter the following error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3997.jdbc.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: JDBC Error 100
Unable to connect. The Infor Compass JDBC Driver.ionapi file is not found. The file must be located in the folder containing the Compass JDBC driver JAR file.

Setup details:
I've initialized my Spark session in Azure Synapse with the required JDBC driver and specified the ionapi file path using spark.jars.
The ionapi file is stored in Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS), and I have ensured the path is correctly specified in the JDBC connection properties.
Code snippet:
%%configure -f

{

"conf": {  

    "spark.jars": "abfss://container@datalake_name.dfs.core.windows.net/infor-compass-jdbc-2023.10.jar",  

}

}

storage_account_name = "**"

container_name = "**"

jdbc_jar_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/path_to_jdbc_driver/infor-compass-jdbc-2023.10.jar"

ionapi_file_path = f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/path_to_ionapi_file/Infor Compass JDBC Driver.ionapi"

spark = SparkSession.builder \

.appName("InforDataLakeConnection") \

.config("spark.jars", jdbc_jar_path) \

.getOrCreate()

jdbc_url = "jdbc:infordatalake://your_infordatalake_endpoint"

jdbc_properties = {

"user": "**",

"password": "**",

"driver": "com.infor.idl.jdbc.Driver", 

"ionapi": ionapi_file_path 
}

table_name = "table_name"

df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=table_name, properties=jdbc_properties)

df.show()

Error analysis: I have verified that ionapi_file_path correctly points to the location of the ionapi file in ADLS. The storage account key used in spark.conf.set matches the correct ADLS storage account.
How to correctly configure the ionapi file path or any additional settings necessary to successfully connect to Infor Data Lake using Spark JDBC in Azure Synapse?
Trying to connect infor datalake using pyspark notebook in Synapse analytics.
Encountering issues, as code is unable to read ionapi file for credentials.


Unable to connect. The Infor Compass JDBC Driver.ionapi file is not found. The file must be located in the folder containing the Compass JDBC driver JAR file.

The ionapi  file does not present in the same directory as Compass JDBC driver JAR file. That may be the reason to get above error.  Copy ionapi  file into JDBC driver JAR file directory and download ionapi  file into local path using below code:
jdbc_jar_dir = "abfss://container@storageacoount.dfs.core.windows.net/pipeline_dev/wms/"
ionapi_file_path = "abfss://container@storageacoount.dfs.core.windows.net/pipeline_dev/wms/Infor Compass JDBC Driver.ionapi"
local_ionapi_path = jdbc_jar_dir + "Infor Compass JDBC Driver.ionapi"
mssparkutils.fs.cp(ionapi_file_path, local_ionapi_path) 

Update your Spark settings to use the local ionapi file path.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
   .appName("InforDataLakeConnection") \
   .config("spark.jars", jdbc_jar_path) \
   .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/path/to/jdbc/driver") \
   .getOrCreate()
jdbc_properties = {
    "user": "**",
    "password": "**",
    "driver": "com.infor.idl.jdbc.Driver",
    "ionapi": local_ionapi_path
}
table_name = "table_name"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table=table_name, properties=jdbc_properties)
df.show()

For more information you can refer similar question in Q&A platform and this document.
